# Launch Screen Components

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, launchimage, launch-screen

I see plenty of applications on the app store that either have blank (black or white) or branded launch screens.  This is in spite of the iOS developer guidelines that state, "the launch image isn't an opportunity to provide branded elements," and it also should be, "identical to the first screen of the app." So I do not know where to draw the line between correct and wrong, but I'm hoping that you guys can help me answer that.

I personally would like to place my company logo on the launch screen and place a duplicate logo on the root view controller where I can then animate it to fade out. (I'm not sure if this method is frowned upon and, if so, would it be rejected?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said yourself, a lot of apps is doing that so you don't have to be worried to be rejected. A nice example is Twitter (a bird with fading).

But still you should reconsider if you really need branding in launch screen. You already have branding in an icon, colors and in other elements.